# Proof NP-Complete for $L = \{G, T \mid G \text{ is a graph with a spanning tree isomorphic to } T\}$

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity, np-complete

$L = \{G, T \mid G \text{ is a graph with a spanning tree isomorphic to } T\}$ and I try to prove it's NP-Completeness. It seems really easy since obviously it is at least as hard as HAM-PATH which is know to be NP-C. However I can't come up with a good reduction. So far I have:

F = "on input G, s, t

1. Construct the spanning tree T by applying breadth first search
   algorithm to $s$:

   1.1. add $s$ to $T$

   1.2. go through each of the neighbors: if neighbor is not in $T$ -> stop
   cycle and do bfs(neigbor)
2. Output $G$, $T$.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ has $n$ vertices, you just want to compare to the path $P_{n}$. So you reduce $HP \leq L$, where $HP$ is Hamiltonian Path.

So let $G$ be a graph with a Hamiltonian Path. We construct an instance of $L$ with parameters $(G, P_{n})$. So suppose $G$ has a Hamiltonian Path. As the Hamiltonian path is a path on $n$ vertices, so $P_{n} \subset G$ and $L$ is satisfied. Conversely, suppose $L$ is satisfied. Then there exists a path of length $n$ in $G$, which is a Hamiltonian path. And so the instance of $HP$ is satisfied. The reduction is constant time, as we aren't modifying $G$. Thus, $L \in \mathcal{NP}$-Hard.

Now just provide the polynomial time verification algorithm, and you are done.

**Edit:** This is too long for a comment, so I will clarify here.

Actually, that is the reduction with detailed steps. Remember that $\mathcal{NP}$ is the class of decision problems where an answer of YES can be verified in polynomial time. So to show $\mathcal{NP}$-Completeness, you need to show the following: 
-A polynomial time verification algorithm, given a correct solution. 
-A polynomial time reduction $HP \leq_{p} L$

In the reduction portion of the proof, you have to argue: 
-Suppose your graph $G$ has a Hamiltonian path. Does that imply an answer of YES to the constructed instance $(G, P_{n})$? That is, does $G$ have a spanning tree isomorphic to $P_{n}$?

-Conversely, suppose the constructed instance $(G, P_{n})$ is satisfied. Does that imply that $G$ has a Hamiltonian path? That is, if $G$ has a spanning tree isomorphic to $P_{n}$, does $G$ have a Hamiltonian path?

Comment: Thank you for good insights, however it doesn't look like a righteous proof to me. I really wanted to construct a reduction with detailed steps. I see the big picture, but I can't describe it precisely. So far I did that:
F = "on input G
1. Construct the path (spanning tree) T by applying breadth first search algorithm to s:
  1.1 add s to T<br>
  1.2 go through each of the neighbors: if neighbor is not in T - stop cycle and do bfs(neigbor)
2. Check the sizes: if G>T, REJECT
3. Output G, T.

Does this one make sense at all?

Comment: I've made an edit to clarify exactly what you need to show. The proof I provided is actually a detailed proof. The reduction step doesn't require an algorithm. Let $G$ be an instance of $HP$ and let $f : HP \to L$ be our reduction. We need to show that $G$ has a Hamiltonian path if and only if $f(G)$ is in $L$. I showed that above. The only place you need an algorithm is the polynomial time verification step.

Comment: @ml0105 I believe an instance of Hamilton path is in the form $\langle G,s,t \rangle$ where $s$ and $t$ are starting and ending vertices of the Hamilton Path. In the answer, the $s$ and $t$ are not considered. Suppose I have a graph in the form $a \rightarrow s \rightarrow t \rightarrow b$, then $\langle G, P_n \rangle \in L$ but $\langle G,s,t \rangle \not\in HP$.

Comment: There are multiple formulations of the HAMILTONIAN PATH problem. You can formulate it in terms of $\langle G, s, t \rangle$ as you specified, or just instances $\langle G \rangle$, where $G$ is a graph with a Hamiltonian path. It may be convenient for certain reductions to formulate it as you did, but not necessary here. The important detail is that we map $\langle G \rangle \mapsto \langle G, P_{n} \rangle$. I'm not sure the point you are making with your example; it doesn't impact the correctness of the reduction.

Answer (score 2):

A Hamiltonian path is a spanning tree isomorphic to a linear graph.